# Right way to select count of rows by single nullable field?

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 5 states of field named 'status' (0..4). I try to find the best way to count every state of field, include 0. There is an example:

```
table Example
  row 1:
    int id=1; string(255) content="some_content"; smallint status=1;
  row 2:
    int id=2; string(255) content="some_content"; smallint status=1;
  row 3:
    int id=3; string(255) content="some_content"; smallint status=0;
  row 4:
    int id=4; string(255) content="some_content"; smallint status=4;
end
```

I want to get result like this: `$result === array (0 => 0, 1 => 2, 2 => 0, 3 => 0, 4 => 1)`

Now I see only one way - create new query for every state, but I'm sure there is a much better way. Can someone help me find it?.. :)

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Show your sample data. Where do you keep all statuses?

Comment: I tried to show it in the question body, but I'll try again. Sry, my bad English skewing my thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a table which holds statuses (need to show those with 0 matching rows) and some other table with data that has a status assigned standard query would be to join these tables, group result and count on appearances in data table:

```
select st.status, count(dt.status)
from status_table st
left join data_table dt on
  st.status = dt.status
group by st.status
```

Even though you could return an array from SQL this wouldn't be an associative array. I would handle the output from database within the application code (PHP in your case).

Comment: I have 'status' field at the same table. But I got your idea, it's wrong to store them togethter. Thanks you very much!

Comment: Yes, you should be storing your available statuses elsewhere (different table) and reference to them using FOREIGN KEY. This will provide normalisation, let you avoid data inconsistency and in general will also let you show those statuses which don't have any occurences, because you can't show a status with 0 rows, if there is no such status, but you got that already - GJ :)